Is $\delta \Delta^{-1} d$ the identity operator?
Let $d, \delta, \Delta = (d\delta + \delta d)$ be the exterior derivative, codifferential and Laplace-de-Rham operator.
Let $\omega$ be a closed $k$-form, one can then say $\Delta \omega = d \delta \omega$. The operator $\Delta^{-1}$ is well defined on a simply connected manifold.
One is tempted to pretend that if $\omega = \Delta^{-1} \theta$ is closed, then $``\Delta^{-1} = (d \delta)^{-1} = \delta^{-1} d^{-1}"$
Does this mean $\delta \Delta^{-1} d \omega = \omega$, perhaps assuming certain topological conditions? How could I properly show this?

$\Delta$ is not invertible, its kernel is isomorphic to the de Rham cohomology of the manifold (supposing that the manifold is compact. Nonetheless $\Delta^{-1}$ is well defined of $d$-exact and also on $\delta$-exact forms; for a $\delta$-exact $\omega$ you would indeed have $\delta \Delta^{-1} d \omega = \omega$ (and for a $d$-exact $d \Delta^{-1} \delta \omega = \omega$)

The statement $\Delta$ is not invertible and $\Delta^{-1}$ exists seems to conflict. But I would guess you are being strict and consider the Biot-Savart kernel not to be a true inverse for functional analytical reasons perhaps. Either way, can you elaborate on how to show the last two claims?

Oh, it's easy isn't it. If $\omega = \delta \theta$ then $d \delta \theta = \Delta \theta$ so the Laplacians cancel and you are left with $\delta \theta$ which was assumed to be $\omega$, right?

Unless there's any important caveat to note, feel free to write your comment as an answer @user8268 and I will accept it. If not I'll mark this as answered later on and credit you.

The Laplacian may be inverted under the assumption of no harmonic appearing in the Hodge decomposition, or working in equivalence classes modulo harmonic forms.
On co-exact forms the Laplacian acts as $d \delta$ and on exact forms as $\delta d$, because if $\omega = \delta \theta$ then $\theta$ can be imposed to be closed, and if $\omega = d \psi$ then $\psi$ can be imposed to be co-closed, (see this question)
It then follows that $\delta \Delta^{-1} d \omega = \delta \Delta^{-1}\Delta \theta = \delta \theta = \omega $ and likewise for the exact case and $d \Delta^{-1}\delta$ as pointed out by user8268
Without the mentioned assumptions the operator is not the identity.
